# Meta-analysis of proportions - how to analyze possible moderators and publication bias?

Tags: stata, random-effects-model, meta-analysis, meta-regression

I am performing a meta-analysis study of proportions in Stata using the `metaprop` command. My data includes 10 studies for which I have the variables: `study, ntotal, nobserved, region, age`. Using `metaprop` is not a problem, but I want to add two additional analyses:

1. an analysis of the possible moderators region, mean age and studysize (ntotal)

I read about the `metareg` command, but I suspect its handling of binominal data is different than `metaprop`? And I fear this to influence the validity of its usage compared to Forest plots based on the `metaprop` command. I run the code:

```
// Generate logged proportion for regression analysis
gen logp = log(nobserved/ntotal)

// Try test for covariates.
metareg logp ntotal age region, wsse(logp)
```

Is this at all a valid approach for the regression analysis?

2. Funnelplot for possible publication bias

Next problem is the funnelplot.  I have access to all data of the included studies, and hence I can calculate proportions and the corresponding standard error:

`proportion agree, over(studyName)`

and putting these values in variables `prop` and `SEp`.

I log the propability, and run the `metabias` command:

```
gen logp = log(prop)

// Funnel plot and Egger
metabias logp SEp, graph(begg)
```

My question is: Are the statistical approach and usage of meta-analysis commands above valid?

Comment: Two comments. (1) with 10 studies three moderators at once is unlikely to show anything convincing, even one is optimistic, (2) I do not see where you calculate the standard errors of your transformed proportions but this may be because I do not speak Stata.

Comment: Indeed, you can easily do this if you use R instead.

Comment: Thank you both. The standard errors are automatically produced by the proportion command. I copy the se for each study into a separate dataset used in the meta analysis. I have tried R many years ago (but not for meta analysis), but everybody at the research department I work at now use Stata...

Comment: @mdewey why will the regression analysis not work with three moderators? I believe I've seen several published examples of this approach...

Comment: You can fit the model but unless you are lucky the standard errors will be large and you will have only vague conclusions.